# How to connect AI neural network processor to laptop?

Tags: neural-networks

I have an average laptop.

How can I connect specialized AI neural network processors (say, Intel Nvidia or Intel Nervana https://venturebeat.com/2018/05/23/intel-unveils-nervana-neural-net-l-1000-for-accelerated-ai-training/) to thelaptop.
Should I buy some external motherboard or even server unit with NN processors inside or is there available more lightweight solution like external HDD?

Comment: are you interested in training or inference?

Comment: I am interested in both training and inference, but I guess that initially could be good to set up at least one process. I guess, that training is the resource consuming process for which the processors are designed, inference can be done with the ordinary processor.

Answer (score 2):

Check of deep learning box on the internet.
You will have to think hard in order to make a good and cost effective one.

But there are a few people who have made one of their own and shared their experiences.

Here are some medium articles:

[Building your own Deep Learning dream machine](https://medium.com/yanda/building-your-own-deep-learning-dream-machine-4f02ccdb0460)

[Building a 270* Teraflops Deep Learning Box for Under $10,000](https://medium.com/intuitionmachine/building-a-270-teraflops-deep-learning-box-of-under-10-000-2d790b0ae2ec)